# Convert from UTC C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, dayjs

Using a combination of server-side C#, SQL database, and the dayjs client-side library [dayjs](https://day.js.org/en/) I am unable to convert the date stored as UTC in the database UTC to local time.

My theory is to store all date-times in the database as UTC. Use the client (browser) to determine the user timezone (automatically or store it for each user), then let the browser, via dayjs convert from UTC time to local time.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a dayjs problem but the way dates are stored in SQL and pulled via C#.

In order for dayjs to convert the DateTime on the client app the date must be returned from the server in a very specific format.

If you are using DateTime C# and SQL datatypes and using just pulling the DateTime straight from the database to a DTO the date will be returned to the client like this:

```
noteDate: "2022-01-06T22:31:34.81"
```

In order for dayjs.tz() method to work the date DateTime must be returned from the server in this format:

```
noteDate: "2022-01-06T22:31:34.81Z"
```

Then this code will property convert from UTC to local time:

```
 let date = "2022-01-06T20:14:18.917Z";
 let timeZoneGuess = dayjs.tz.guess();
 date = dayjs(date).tz(timeZoneGuess);
```

To get this format to the client I had to add additional information to the DateTime before returning the note.NoteDate to the client.

```
note.NoteDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(note.NoteDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

When storing the DateTime in SQL I am using c# DateTime and SQL DateTime datatypes. When setting the note.NoteDate I call note.NoteDate = DateTime.UtcNow but apparently SQL does not save the "Z" part of the UTC date.

I would like to see if anyone else has this same issue and if there are better ways to solve it.

Comment: How about to use C# DateTimeOffset and SQL Server datetimeoffset? Both stores time zone offset information. And you don't have to use dayjs to convert to local time because Javascript Date class has time zone information.